# How to have straight single quotes in lstlistings

Tags: listings, punctuation

All single quotes in code samples are displayed as backticks and the copy-pasted code can't be compiled without fixing the quotation. Is it possible to prevent this?

for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Python}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
print 'hi' 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `latexmk -pdf file.tex`, which creates a log starting like: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)`.

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about your document and TeX system setup. E.g., do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document? To help narrow down the list of things to consider, please provide a full MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`) that produces the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

Comment: @Mico, thanks, added minimal code. I hope this is sufficient.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to load the `textcomp` package and add `upquote=true` to your `\lstset` command.  See §4.7 of the `listings` documentation.  Alternatively, you can simply load the `upquote` package, which will make *all* verbatim quotes single quotes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Python,upquote=true}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
print 'hi' 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: You could simply load the package `upquote`...

Comment: inside the beamer document class, one must add the ``[fragile]`` option, i.e. ``\begin{frame}[fragile]`` (as far as I can tell, it fails without it)

Comment: @PatrickT Yes, that's what the example code shows. Since it was already in the code posted in the question I didn't mention it explicitly. But `beamer` requires any verbatim text to be in a `[fragile]` frame.

Comment: @AlanMunn, True. In my code, ``[fragile]`` was the missing part that caused an error, so I thought I'd point it out explicitly.

Comment: The sourcecodepro font doesn't include ` so you might need to change font too. I'm currently using inconsolata to get around this problem.

Comment: Starting with the 2020/02/02 release of the LaTeX format, it's no longer necessary to load the `textcomp` package in order to use the option `upquote=true`.

Answer (score -2):

Try using ` (the symbol before the the numerical key of 1 above the alphabetical keys, it is on the key that shows: ~, when used with shift!). It works for me while creating documents.

So, essentially it will look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Python}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
print `hi' 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

-Sameer

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.sx.  You may want to check out our starter guide: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This answer unfortunately doesn't actually answer the question. You've shown (correctly) how to get the correct curly quotes, but the question is asking how to get two identical straight quotes.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks. Will take care next time. This was my first attempt to answer!

Comment: Apparently, it was user 33989 first and last attemps ;-)

Comment: The issue I found with this (if I'm fine with curly quotes) was that the listings package would not properly color my code with this method. It would not recognize a backtick as a quote character but it would recognize the apostrophe/regular single quote, so then my code was colored to appear as if the ending quote actually began a string literal. So, just as a warning to others, it seems the above method is not entirely sufficient even for curly quotes.