# How can I get straight double quotes in listings?

Tags: symbols, listings, textcomp

My question is related to the following two

- [How to have straight single quotes in lstlistings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145416/how-to-have-straight-single-quotes-in-lstlistings?lq=1)
- [In the minted package, how do I enforce straight single quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46880/in-the-minted-package-how-do-i-enforce-straight-single-quotes)

but I'm specifically asking about double-quote characters (ASCII decimal code 34).
They appear curly in my listings. How can I get straight double quotes instead?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,upquote,listings}
\lstset{upquote=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
echo "Hello, world!"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

produces

> [image: Output of the provided MWE; contains closing curly quotes]

I understand that the `upquote` package only applies to single quotes. How can I make it apply to double quotes as well?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simply add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble. Note that you don't need the `upquote` package if you load `textcomp` and set `listings`' `upquote` key to `true`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{upquote=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
echo "Hello, world!"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to show the quotation as [example1](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/09/26/59ca2c9c1c365.png) or [example2](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/09/26/59ca2cd6bfc41.png)

Comment: @jubobs could you please elaborate on this example a bit? The `listings.sty` file actually only handles single quotes, but your example does compiles to straight double quotes. However, I ran into [a failed example](https://github.com/be5invis/Sarasa-Gothic/issues/55#issue-372876077) as well.

Comment: @wlnirvana Your problem probably deserves a brand new question on this site.

Comment: `\setmonofont{Consolas}` voids the effects. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

For, me the above solutions did not work.

The main problem can be seen in `listings.sty`, lines 922-943, where a dispatch table of handling special characters in created, but the upquote is only done for single quotes.

One can fix this by adding the following to your preamble:

```tex
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{upquote=true}
% ...
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"22}{\lst@ifupquote \textquotedbl
                                     \else \char34\relax \fi}
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother
% ...
```

which monkey-patches that table.

**Caveat emptor**: this is a terrible hack which relies on modifying internal macros of the listings package.  This may arbitrarily and completely break and may even not work on your TeX distro.

Comment: It may be a terrible hack, but at least it works \\_o_/.

Comment: I only added `\lstset{upquote=true}` to the preamble, one line, and it worked, i.e. straight single or double quotes.

Comment: I prefer this because I was using the metropolis theme and using the T1 fontenc would change the entire font; thank you, @summentier!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XeLaTeX and you want to change the font (say, to use the default typewriter font), use the `fontspec` package to turn off TeX ligatures, as follows:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\addfontfeature{Mapping=no-mapping-ligtex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
echo "Hello, world!"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! None of the other answers worked for me on XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for double quotes showing up as curly is the usage of TeX ligatures — this is already mentioned in [AthanasiusOfAlex's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639614/91770). As I discovered, one way these ligatures can be (often inadvertently) enabled is through the usage of a line such as

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
```

This line ensures that TeX ligatures are enabled for *all* fonts, including any monospaced fonts subsequently defined using `\setmonofont`. This then leads to curly quotes in listings which couldn't be solved using any of the other answers.

If you have such a line, get rid of it. The `fontspec` package already enables TeX ligatures by default for the `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` commands, which probably correspond to the fonts where you *do* want the ligatures. (This is mentioned in Part II, Section 1 of the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf).)

If you then want to type an em dash (for example) in the code listing, just use the actual Unicode symbol for it (`—`) instead of typing three hyphens `---`.