# Questions about including source code in a TeX file

Tags: listings, typewriter

I'd like to include some Sage code in a TeX file. Originally I thought the right way would be to use `$\texttt{}$` whenever I had to include the source code, but then I ran into some difficulties:

1. When my code contained something like `$2^3$` and I entered it as `\texttt{2^3}` I got error messages.
2. Whenever I needed straight single quotes I got curved ones.

I managed to solve the first issue by typing `\texttt{2\textasciicircum 3}`, but didn't find a fix for the second one, so I started searching the web. This way I came to know `listing` environment that I'd never used before. Since Sage is not listed as a language for listing, I entered Python instead, however the spacing is not right and the output does not look like that of `\texttt`. So I wonder:

what is the right way of entering Sage code in LaTeX? I apologize if this question has already been answered , but I couldn't locate it myself.

```
\documentclass{article,amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Python}
\begin{lstlisting}
sqrt(9)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the question is not really very clear about what output you expect. If you are not looking for syntax highlighting then `\verb|x^2|` for inline fragments or `\begin{verbatim}`... `\end{verbatim}` for a code block.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! verbatim does the job. It might be a stupid question, but since I'm totally new to listing, can you please clarify whether listings environment has any usage for typing Sage code in LaTeX?

Comment: listings allows (simple) customisation of keywords so you could set up some sage highlighting probably but I know nothing about sage, verbatim is built in to latex and just does straight typewritter emulation. The other main syntax highlighter package is  minted (which uses the external python pygments library, so if there is a pygments setup for sage you could use that)

Comment: I'd definitely recommend the `listings` package for longer code blocks; see [this post](https://mvngu.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/typesetting-sage-code-listings-in-latex/) for some ideas about how to highlight it nicely. As for straight quotes in `listings`, see [this TeX.SX post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166791/55879).

Comment: Many thanks @DavidCarlisle! By the way is there any difference between \verb and \texttt commands?

Comment: @ArunDebray The blog post looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! It should be useful in the future.

Comment: upon further searching I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt

Comment: perhaps this is overkill, but the package `sagetex` does provide a command explicitly for typesetting sage code in a latex document.  look at the [`sagetex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf).

Comment: @barbarabeeton This is great! I went through the first 15 pages or so and looks like a good investment. Thanks much!

Comment: glad to be of help.  there was a [tugboat article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-3/tb102joshi.pdf) a while back that you might also find interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use Sage code in a LaTeX document then you should use the `sagetex` package. According to this [CTAN document](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf), `sagetex` has several verbatim like environments. It sounds like you want the `sageverbatim` environment. In using this environment, "... whatever  you  type  will
be typeset, but not written into the .sage file.  This allows you to typeset psue-docode, code that will fail, or take too much time to execute, or whatever". Using the built in environment gives you access to \sagetexindent, which lets you control the indentation of the code.

But if you want to make your code typeset even nicer, then you should consider copying the tex file of William Stein--the driving force behind Sage. Download the paper (www.wstein.org/papers/icms/stein-icms2010.tar.bz2), extract the contents and run it through LaTeX to get the output of his paper shown below:
[image]

If you look at the right panel you'll see, under the image of the car, the Sage code with code spruced up. Check the preamble of the file and find
out how he used \lstdefinelanguage{Sage}[]{Python}
[image]

You can start with his paper preamble and modify his code to suit your needs. I don't see, however, a way to make the curved single quotes straight.

Comment: Thanks! Btw I learned a simple way to make single quotes straight that I include here: you need to add \usepackage{upquote} in the preamble and that takes care of the rest!

Comment: Thanks for the information; I wasn't fond of the curved single quote either.