# How to display the output of a loop in SageTex

Tags: sagetex

I am preparing a class on Sage, and i want the following code on my document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}

\begin{sagecommandline}
sage: for i in range(0,4):
....:     i^2
\end{sagecommandline}

\end{document}
```

However, i want it to display the output as it does in a Sage worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with your code, I'd try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\lstdefinestyle{SageInput}{style=DefaultSageInput, numbers=none}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagecommandline}
sage: for i in range(0,4):
....:     i^2
\end{sagecommandline}
\begin{sagesilent}
output = r""
for i in range(0,4):
    output += r"\texttt{%s}\\"%(i^2)  
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output running in Cocalc is:
[image]

The code `numbers=none` turns off the line numbers, if that's something you wanted.

You might also be interested to know that my answer to the question [Questions about including source code in a TeX file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283108/questions-about-including-source-code-in-a-tex-file/283301#283301) mentions that one of the developers of SAGE has posted a LaTeX file that he uses in typesetting SAGE.

Comment: Could you help me solve my problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543396/how-to-execute-sagetex-code-multiple-times-with-loop)?