# sagetex linebreak

Tags: listings, line-breaking, sagetex

When using the environment `sagecommandline` of sagetex with long number output, how can I get automatic line breaks?
I already tried to change sagetex.sty (putting `breaklines=true` at several places), but nothing changed. Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[
a6paper, 11pt, oneside,
english,ngerman]{scrartcl} 

% !TEX TS-program = sage
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\usepackage[headsep=0cm,footskip=1.5em,includeheadfoot=true,
top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=.5cm,right=.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\lstdefinestyle{SageOutput}{style=DefaultSageOutput,breaklines=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{sagecommandline}
sage: factorial(100)+1
sage: factorial(50)+1
sage: factorial(10)
\end{sagecommandline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. You could, however, get around it by combining the Sagemath template Dr Stein provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283108/questions-about-including-source-code-in-a-tex-file) combined with generating the nice looking output, like in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511181/how-to-display-the-output-of-a-loop-in-sagetex) using `sagesilent` and `\sagestr` whenever the output overflows. I think you'd have to get rid of line numbers to do this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I can ... I found a solution myself:

```
\documentclass[ DIV=16, a6paper, 11pt]{scrartcl} 
% arara: lualatex
% arara: sagetex
% arara: lualatex
% !TEX TS-program = sage
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\lstset{
literate=
{1}{1\allowbreak}1
{2}{2\allowbreak}1
{3}{3\allowbreak}1
{4}{4\allowbreak}1
{5}{5\allowbreak}1
{6}{6\allowbreak}1
{7}{7\allowbreak}1
{8}{8\allowbreak}1
{9}{9\allowbreak}1
{0}{0\allowbreak}1,
breaklines=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagecommandline}
sage: factorial(50)
\end{sagecommandline}
\seqsplit{%
30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great: +1, but people come to this site looking for answers that can help with their problems, too. Was the `seqsplit` package all that was needed? What does `\lstset{
literate=` do? How about `\allowbreak`?

Comment: a) 'seqsplit' does not work inside the env. sagecommandline, but inside math; I added it just for the sake of completeness; perhaps I should have left it out in order to not confuse people ... b) lstset{literate=...} is an option of the listings package; when having breaklines=true, this is not enough, you also have to tell listings that it is allowed to insert linebreaks after the figures 0, 1, ..., 9, which is not the case usually;