# How to have free accents in `lstlisting`

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

There are quite some questions about getting accents like è into the `lstlisting` environment. But I actually want to have a free floating accent. However, Latex always changes it to some other symbol so copy pasting the  code will not work.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    `if`(...)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding copy/paste from listings, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195495/21891

Comment: Different question from [listings - How to have straight single quotes in lstlistings - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145416/how-to-have-straight-single-quotes-in-lstlistings), but same workaround applies. (for the purpose of *copy paste* alternative includes make the display smart quote but copy as normal as well.) Alternative includes using literate option [listings - Problems with copy and paste from PDF using lstlisting - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51604/problems-with-copy-and-paste-from-pdf-using-lstlisting/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `upquote` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    `if`(...)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For using BeraMono:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    `if`(...)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would there be any alternative for `BeraMono` font?

Comment: It works also with BeraMono, I'll add an example